# Django3 Include path/The include urls.py not showing up the templates

Tags: django-urls, django-3.0

I am pretty new to python Django; I am trying to figure out what exactly I am missing from the last few hours.
here is my code structure

url.py

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('signup', views.signupuser, name="signupuser"),

    path ('', views.home, name='home'),
   
    path ('socialcard', views.create_social_card, name='create_social_card'),

    path ('dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
  
   
]
```

Then I created another URL set in the dashboard app; here is the code.

```
From django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def dashboard(request):
    home="dashboard"
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'home':home})
```

I am getting the following error,

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /dashboard/
> dashboard.html

I don't know what I am missing, I have added the templates folder in the app and have also added the subfolder dashboard. like this dashboard/templates/dashboard, and then there reside dashboard.html

When I add the template path as base.html, it loads up an empty page, doesn't display any error. So I don't know what exactly I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Well as all beginners do silly mistakes...I forgot to define my app in the setting.
I would advise all beginners that add the app in the setting as soon as you start an app.